# How to handle concurrent updates and reads to a POJO stored in a Map

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am planning to implement a simple in-memory cache for lookup using CHM which operated by at most 2 concurrent threads. One thread iterating and updating the CHM using iterator and the second thread reading the values from the map.

As my understanding goes and what I have experienced till now CHM Iterator is fail safe which would mean iteration would happen on a snapshot of data.

So let's assume Thread A extracts a value from CHM which is a POJO using a key and it is iterating/updating the POJO. At the same time ThreadB does a get on the same POJO. So what would be the expected behavior at this point?

- Will ThreadB see the updates which ThreadA is making? I guess not because ThreadA is still in the middle of making updates.
- If yes please share your thoughts how will that happen?
- If not please suggest efficient alternate ways if you have implemented any.

POJO is something like below.

```
Class Pojo{
    private volatile long a;
    private volatile long b;
    ....    

    public long getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    void setA(long a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for learning or production? If it's for production, use something that's been battle tested: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Answer (score 2):

> As my understanding goes and what I have experienced till now CHM Iterator is fail safe which would mean iteration would happen on a snapshot of data.

This is not correct. Per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at **or since** the creation of the iterator/enumeration.

[emphasis mine]

---

> So let's assume Thread A extracts a value from CHM which is a POJO using a key and it is iterating/updating the POJO. At the same time ThreadB does a get on the same POJO. So what would be the expected behavior at this point?

If Thread A is mutating a POJO while Thread B is examining the same POJO, then the ConcurrentHashMap is not relevant at all: it doesn't much matter how the two threads *got* the POJO, only how the POJO itself handles concurrent updates and reads.

You haven't told us anything about the POJO class, but unless it's been carefully designed to allow atomic updates and reads, it's more-or-less a given that Thread B will sometimes view the POJO in an inconsistent state, with some of Thread A's reads but not all of them.

Comment: Even if the POJO class is designed carefully to allow atomic updates/reads, there is still a possibility of missing the update if the write is initiated after the read.

Comment: @CKing: I think that's a given -- no one expects reads to read from the future, nor writes to write into the past.

Comment: Exactly. And this is why the OP needs to rethink the use of a `ConcurrentHashMap` because there is still no assurance that updates will not be missed which is what the OP wants. A better approach would have been to use a `BlockingQueue` where one thread created and writes the POJO to the queue and the other thread reads it. With this approach, it is guaranteed that writes are not missed and you also get the parrellelization..

Comment: @CKing: I'm not sure how you determined that "what the OP wants" is "assurance that updates will not be missed"; that's not at all how I interpret his/her desire for a "cache for lookup".

Comment: *"Will ThreadB see the updates which ThreadA is making? I guess not because ThreadA is still in the middle of making updates."* **And..** *"If yes please share your thoughts how will that happen"*.. **And..** *"If not please suggest efficient alternate ways if you have implemented any."*. To me, these are clear indications that the OP wants a way to solve these problems. Specially the last point of an alternate solution to address these points. That said, you are right about the OP wanting a cache so a blocking queue doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CKing: Oh, I see -- I was thinking the OP was *worried* that Thread B would see in-progress writes, but you're right, it actually seems that the OP is *hoping* that Thread B will see in-progress writes. Hmm. This may be one of those cases where the OP doesn't understand the problem space well enough to ask a Stack Overflow question that will solve his/her problem. :-/

Comment: I agree. When it comes to a cache, one always needs to understand the tradeoffs between supporting a particular use-case vs performance requirements. The OP needs to understand these tradeoffs..

Answer (score 0):

Well can't you do something like this.

```
Pojo myPojo = new Pojo();
myPojo.setA(10);
myPojo.setB(11);

// Atomic replace
CHM.replace(key, myPojo);
```

CHM replace is atomic which no other thread would read stale value of the POJO while replace is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

- The value of your CHM should be AtomicReference
- Make Pojo class immutable, updating any new value should create a new Pojo object.
- Implement a constructor that accepts all the parameters in the constructor.
- Implement each set method like example given below

> ```
> public Pojo setA(int newA ){
>     Pojo newPojo = new Pojo(newA, this.getB());
>     return newPojo;
> }
> ```

- While updating the CHM follow steps

> ```
> AtomicReference pojoRef = CHM.get(Key);
> Pojo oldPojo = pojoRef.get();
> Pojo newPojo = oldPojo.setA(10);
> while(!pojoRef.compareAndSet(oldPojo, newPojo) ){
>     AtomicReference pojoRef = CHM.get(Key);
>     Pojo oldPojo = pojoRef.get();
>     Pojo newPojo = oldPojo.setA(10);
> }
> ```